# Bhagavad Gita for Kids

Tags: bhagavad-gita, book-recommendation

Namaskar,

I started reading Bhagavad  Gita a few months ago. I am reading shlokas, and their translations from Gita Press version.

Now I have a small daughter(7-8 years old). I  daily tell/read her stories from books like Panchatantra, Jataka Tales, etc. before she goes to bed. She loves them. Yesterday she saw me reading Bhagavad Gita, and now she is insisting me to tell more about chapters/lessons/shlokas from Bhagavad Gita as a bedtime story.

Now I am genuinely worried as I absolutely can not say No to her, but I don't have a deeper understanding of the shlokas. I know the literal translation of shlokas and all, but it would be too much abstractness and rigor  for a child's mind.

Do you know any version of Bhagavad  Gita which aims at students and children? I mean I am looking for some text which tells the abstract and deep shlokas in some story format which may be easily understandable for kids and which I can read her as a bedtime story.

Comment: In my view, it is not advisable to try for such books - Bhagavid Gita - Made easy - :).  It is a treatise on ABSTRACT concepts. it is better if stories on Ramayana and Mahabharata, prepared for children (Amarchitra katha) can be read out.@StammeringMathematician

Comment: You can take help of such sites which are designed for children in the dialog form - https://gita-society.com/bhagavadgita_children.html

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way here is the whole book for download - https://archive.org/details/THEBHAGAVADGITAFORKIDS/page/n1

Comment: @SwiftPushkar convert your comments into answer.